# Why am I not on my checkbooks bank account?

Tags: scams, fraud

My boyfriend says that he added me to his Wells Fargo account and I received 5 checkbooks, a balance book and wallet from Wells Fargo. Packaging appeared official but when I went to the bank they said I was not on the account and refused to answer any questions or give me any information. I just wanted to know how it’s possible to get checks in my name and address on them and I am not on the bank account?

Comment: Did you show the chequebooks to the bank teller?  Did they have anything to say about its appearance?  Probably also worth clarifying the point raised in Vicky's answer: how well do you actually know this "boyfriend"?  Is it a local or long distance relationship, and how long has it been going on?  This would tell us a lot about whether it's a complete scam, or just your boyfriend being dodgey about sharing his account, or perhaps just an honest banking error.

Answer (score 12):

Anyone can print this stuff and make it look official. Have you met your boyfriend in person, or only online? I'm afraid if you haven't met him in person this is very likely to be the beginnings of a scam and you would be safest to cut off contact and move on. I'm sorry.

Comment: It's also possible that it could be some sort of scam even if you've met him in person.  I can't think of an honest reason why he would want to add you to a personal account.  If you have joint expenses, it's easier & safer just to do transfers, or set up a joint account.  (Not to mention that these days, there's really no reason for an individual to have 5 books of checks at a time - I've been on my current book of 25 checks since 2012 :-))

Comment: Not only can they print stuff and make it look official. You can pretty much order checks online with anything you want printed on them. Doesn't mean the bank will honor them, but printing companies will pretty much put anything on any kind of paper you ask them to.